# Usage of "in a pearl chain fashion" as a synonym for "sequentially" (pulling material containers with fixed sequence)

Tags: synonyms

I am constantly tempted to say that "material can be pulled in a pearl chain fashion". This shall mean that material containers are lined up like a chain and someone pulls them one-by-one into the manufacturing area (not really, but conceptually). I could probably also use sequentially, but I like pearl chain fashion.

Is that understandable or should I avoid this?

Is there a better word for pulling more or less identical sized material containers in fixed sequence one by one into the manufacturing area?

Pearl chain is supposed to mean something like "pearl necklace" or "bead chain" and may be a false friend (The German "Perlenkette" means pearl necklace in German and is directly translated to Pearl Chain).

Comment: When you say 'pearl chain', I assume you mean what I would call a 'string of beads'?

Comment: I do see "pearl chain formation" and "pearl-chain fashion" in Google Books, but I don't know how common the expression is or how immediately it would be understood. It may depend on your audience.

Comment: I might call it a *"**conveyor belt**" continuous production process*. But [this guy](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/continuous-delivery-like-conveyor-belt-benny-van-de-sompele) disagrees.

Comment: I for one would not have the slightest idea what you were talking about.  But maybe this is technical language from a certain field?

Comment: Google Ngrams suggests both "chain of pearls" and "pearl chain" are common, but the former is more English and the latter more American.

Comment: @stuartF Well, does that mean that pearl chain is used for pearl necklace? Do you maybe have a source for that (except google ngram)? Then My original question stands: Can I say "pearl chain fashion" to express that something "looks" or has the concept of a "pearl chain"?